# Typed Racket: Natural Numbers

Tags: recursion, racket, typed-racket

I have to solve a problem with a unique definition of the natural numbers:

```
(define-type Nat (U 'Zero Succ))
(define-struct Succ ([prev : Nat]) #:transparent)
```

So basically, `0 = 'Zero, 1 = (Succ 'Zero), 2 = (Succ (Succ 'Zero))....` etc.

Using this form, without converting them into integers, I have write recursive functions to add, subtract, and multiply the natural numbers. For the add function I've tried this

```
(: nat+ : Nat Nat -> Nat)
(define (nat+ n m)
  (match '(n m)
    ['('Zero 'Zero) 'Zero]
    ['((Succ p) 'Zero)
     n]
    ['('Zero (Succ p))
     m]
    ['((Succ p) (Succ t))
     (nat+ p (Succ m))]))
```

but I get the error

> p: unbound identifier in module in: p.

Does anyone have any advice for writing this type of recursive function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of quoting. When you quote a list, say `'(n m)`, it doesn't mean "a list containing whatever `n` is and whatever `m` is - it means a list containing the *literal symbols* `n` and `m`. Quoting things completely ignores whatever bindings they have and only gives you the *literal* interpretation of whatever you quote. So when you do `match '(n m)`, you are *not* matching a list containing the values `n` and `m` are bound to, you are matching a list containing the symbols `n` and `m`. Similar problems exist with your usage of quote everywhere else - in the pattern matching clauses you have to use `list` instead of quote to get the behavior you expect:

```
(: nat+ : Nat Nat -> Nat)
(define (nat+ n m)
  (match (list n m)
    [(list 'Zero 'Zero) 'Zero]
    [(list (Succ p) 'Zero) n]
    [(list 'Zero (Succ p)) m]
    [(list (Succ p) (Succ t)) (nat+ p (Succ m))]))
```

Note that the use of quote remains in `'Zero` - this is because `Zero` is not a binding with a value, you're using the literal symbol `Zero` so it's quoted.

---

Additionally, you can make this more succinct by using the [`define/match`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._define%2Fmatch%29%29) form:

```
(: nat+ : Nat Nat -> Nat)
(define/match (nat+ n m)
  [('Zero 'Zero) 'Zero]
  [((Succ p) 'Zero) n]
  [('Zero (Succ p)) m]
  [((Succ p) (Succ t)) (nat+ p (Succ m))])
```

This form lets you match against the arguments directly, instead of having to pack them together into a list first.